# How to force a part of the React App to load dynamically (on request)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, bundle

I have a React Application which contains two parts: the title part (a presentation screen which is short in size) and the main part (which is huge). I need to divide this app into two modules so each module has its own JS and CSS part and the main part should be loaded on demand, only when the user decided to continue using an app and clicked to "Continue" on the title screen.

So 
1. Title part should be loaded and run always
2. The main part should be loaded and run on demand only

How do I split the application into two different JS and CSS files? How should I write in the code to include and run the main part?

I am a novice in React, please help.

P.S. I found this [link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/bundle-loader) recently but not sure if it is the thing I need to use and also I still don't understand how to divide the App into 2 parts.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to achieve conditional rendering (load after click in your case), but you have to add some more information about your application - what will happen when the user clicks the button (will it load data from the server - if yes - how  and where will you store it, will it use local components, what is your final goal and etc.). Perhaps share some code, so we can help you integrate an idea in your solution.

Comment: @Enchew It's a web-based application that is intended to be run into an iframe on other websites. First of all, people may insert dozen and more application iframes into the same page, that's why the title screen of the application is done simple and lightweight. But the main part of the application is huge and should be loaded and run only if the client clicked to the "Continue" button on the title screen. The idea is pretty much like Youtube, but it's different.

Comment: @Enchew the main part of the application should be loaded only if the user clicked to "Continue" button on the title screen. With this "Continue" button press it will hide the title screen and then LOAD the main bundle from our server. This main part also will connect itself to the server via WebSockets to exchange data etc etc. But the main problem now is to download main part dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself. There is a good starting point at the ReactJS documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Exactly what I need.